# log4net - publish from VSIDE work but MSBuild(using NANT) doesnt

Tags: msbuild, log4net

log4net generates logfiles when i used the Published version of VSIDE but when I build the same project with MSBuild.exe no logfiles are created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its was the build scripts and nothing to do with MSBUILD.exe

Log4Net configuration specified the AssemblyInfo.cs, was overwritten by Build script for version stamping.

Moved the Log4net.Xml....Configure() to Program.cs & Global.asax.cs's Application_Start